# Is there a way to verify the order of spy executions with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I've got two objects that have been set up as spies with Jasmine:

```
spyOn(obj, 'spy1');
spyOn(obj, 'spy2');
```

I need to verify that calls to `spy1` come before calls to `spy2`. I can check if both of them are called:

```
expect(obj.spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(obj.spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but this will pass even if `obj.spy2()` was called first. Is there an easy way of verifying that one was called before the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like the Jasmine folks saw this post or others like it, because [this functionality exists](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledBefore). I'm not sure how long it's been around -- all of their API docs back to 2.6 mention it, though none of their archived older style docs mention it.

> toHaveBeenCalledBefore(`expected`)
>   [expect](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/global.html#expect) the actual value (a [Spy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html)) to have been called before another [Spy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html).
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> Name        Type    Description
> expected    Spy     Spy that should have been called after the actual Spy.
> ```

A failure for your example looks like `Expected spy spy1 to have been called before spy spy2`.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to keep a list of calls:

```
var objCallOrder;
beforeEach(function() {
  // Reset the list before each test
  objCallOrder = [];
  // Append the method name to the call list
  obj.spy1.and.callFake(function() { objCallOrder.push('spy1'); });
  obj.spy2.and.callFake(function() { objCallOrder.push('spy2'); });
});
```

Which lets you check the order in a few different ways:

**Directly compare to the call list:**

```
it('calls exactly spy1 then spy2', function() {
  obj.spy1();
  obj.spy2();

  expect(objCallOrder).toEqual(['spy1', 'spy2']);
});
```

**Check the relative order of a few of the calls:**

```
it('calls spy2 sometime after calling spy1', function() {
  obj.spy1();
  obj.spy3();
  obj.spy4(); 
  obj.spy2();

  expect(obj.spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(obj.spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(objCallOrder.indexOf('spy1')).toBeLessThan(objCallOrder.indexOf('spy2'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

So far I've been doing it as follows, but it seems awkward and won't scale well:

```
obj.spy1.andCallFake(function() {
    expect(obj.spy2.calls.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: I think this works well, I can't think of a better general approach anyway. What would make your intentions clearer though would be this subtle variation: `obj.spy1.andCallFake(function() {
  expect(obj.spy2).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
});` (in Jasmine v2 that would be: `obj.spy1.and.callFake(function() {
  expect(obj.spy2).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
});`)