# How to test that one function is called before another

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some tightly coupled legacy code that I want to cover with tests. Sometimes it's important to ensure that one mocked out method is called before another. A simplified example:

```
function PageManager(page) {
    this.page = page;
}
PageManager.prototype.openSettings = function(){
    this.page.open();
    this.page.setTitle("Settings");
};
```

In the test I can check that both `open()` and `setTitle()` are called:

```
describe("PageManager.openSettings()", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.page = jasmine.createSpyObj("MockPage", ["open", "setTitle"]);
        this.manager = new PageManager(this.page);
        this.manager.openSettings();
    });

    it("opens page", function() {
        expect(this.page.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });

    it("sets page title to 'Settings'", function() {
        expect(this.page.setTitle).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Settings");
    });
});
```

But `setTitle()` will only work after first calling `open()`. I'd like to check that first `page.open()` is called, followed by `setTitle()`. I'd like to write something like this:

```
it("opens page before setting title", function() {
    expect(this.page.open).toHaveBeenCalledBefore(this.page.setTitle);
});
```

But Jasmine doesn't seem to have such functionality built in.

I can hack up something like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    this.page = jasmine.createSpyObj("MockPage", ["open", "setTitle"]);
    this.manager = new PageManager(this.page);

    // track the order of methods called
    this.calls = [];
    this.page.open.and.callFake(function() {
        this.calls.push("open");
    }.bind(this));
    this.page.setTitle.and.callFake(function() {
        this.calls.push("setTitle");
    }.bind(this));

    this.manager.openSettings();
});

it("opens page before setting title", function() {
    expect(this.calls).toEqual(["open", "setTitle"]);
});
```

This works, but I'm wondering whether there is some simpler way to achieve this. Or some nice way to generalize this so I wouldn't need to duplicate this code in other tests.

**PS.** Of course the right way is to refactor the code to eliminate this kind of temporal coupling. It might not always be possible though, e.g. when interfacing with third party libraries. Anyway... I'd like to first cover the existing code with tests, modifying it as little as possible, before delving into further refactorings.

Comment: Is there something you can assert on except that `open` has been called? Like some DOM node change or other "global" data?

Comment: No. The point is that I'm mocking it out - I don't want the actual `open` to be called, especially because it might affect some global state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to verify the order of spy executions with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055781/is-there-a-way-to-verify-the-order-of-spy-executions-with-jasmine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
it("setTitle is invoked after open", function() {
    var orderCop = jasmine.createSpy('orderCop');
    this.page.open = jasmine.createSpy('openSpy').and.callFake(function() {
        orderCop('fisrtInvoke');
    });

    this.page.setTitle = jasmine.createSpy('setTitleSpy').and.callFake(function() {
        orderCop('secondInvoke');
    });

    this.manager.openSettings();

    expect(orderCop.calls.count()).toBe(2);
    expect(orderCop.calls.first().args[0]).toBe('firstInvoke');
    expect(orderCop.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toBe('secondInvoke');
}
```

EDIT: I just realized my original answer is effectively the same as the hack you mentioned in the question but with more overhead in setting up a spy. It's probably simpler doing it with your "hack" way:

```
it("setTitle is invoked after open", function() {
    var orderCop = []
    this.page.open = jasmine.createSpy('openSpy').and.callFake(function() {
        orderCop.push('fisrtInvoke');
    });

    this.page.setTitle = jasmine.createSpy('setTitleSpy').and.callFake(function() {
        orderCop.push('secondInvoke');
    });

    this.manager.openSettings();

    expect(orderCop.length).toBe(2);
    expect(orderCop[0]).toBe('firstInvoke');
    expect(orderCop[1]).toBe('secondInvoke');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> I'd like to write something like this:
>
> ```
> it("opens page before setting title", function() {
>     expect(this.page.open).toHaveBeenCalledBefore(this.page.setTitle);
> });
> ```
>
> But Jasmine doesn't seem to have such functionality built in.

Looks like the Jasmine folks saw this post, because [this functionality exists](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledBefore). I'm not sure how long it's been around -- all of their API docs back to 2.6 mention it, though none of their archived older style docs mention it.

> toHaveBeenCalledBefore(`expected`)
>   [expect](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/global.html#expect) the actual value (a [Spy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html)) to have been called before another [Spy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html).
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> Name        Type    Description
> expected    Spy     Spy that should have been called after the actual Spy.
> ```

A failure for your example looks like `Expected spy open to have been called before spy setTitle`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a fake function for the second call that expects the first call to have been made

```
it("opens page before setting title", function() {

    // When page.setTitle is called, ensure that page.open has already been called
    this.page.setTitle.and.callFake(function() {
        expect(this.page.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })

    this.manager.openSettings();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the specific calls by using the [`.calls.first()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-29) and [`.calls.mostRecent()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-28) methods on the spy.

Comment: This only helps when comparing calls of one method - whether `foo()` was called first with argument `"a"` or `"b"` - but it's of no help when deciding whether method `foo()` was called before method `bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically did the same thing. I felt confident doing this because I mocked out the function behaviors with fully synchronous implementations.

```
it 'should invoke an options pre-mixing hook before a mixin pre-mixing hook', ->
    call_sequence = []

    mix_opts = {premixing_hook: -> call_sequence.push 1}
    @mixin.premixing_hook = -> call_sequence.push 2

    spyOn(mix_opts, 'premixing_hook').and.callThrough()
    spyOn(@mixin, 'premixing_hook').and.callThrough()

    class Example
    Example.mixinto_proto @mixin, mix_opts, ['arg1', 'arg2']

    expect(mix_opts.premixing_hook).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['arg1', 'arg2'])
    expect(@mixin.premixing_hook).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['arg1', 'arg2'])
    expect(call_sequence).toEqual [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've developed a replacement for Jasmine spies, called [strict-spies](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/strict-spies), which solves this problem among many others:

```
describe("PageManager.openSettings()", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.spies = new StrictSpies();
        this.page = this.spies.createObj("MockPage", ["open", "setTitle"]);

        this.manager = new PageManager(this.page);
        this.manager.openSettings();
    });

    it("opens page and sets title to 'Settings'", function() {
        expect(this.spies).toHaveCalls([
            ["open"],
            ["setTitle", "Settings"],
        ]);
    });
});
```